# I can access my context's object, but cant update any of it's values

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Im trying to use React's context API to manage a global state. However I can't figure out how to update, the context and then retrieve updated context values.

I am able to get an object back containing all of the context, when I console.log(this.context), but console.log(this.context.user), returns "undefined".

FeedContext.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

    const FeedContext = React.createContext({
      Feed: [],
      user: '',
      error: null,
      setError: () => {},
      clearError: () => {},
      setFeed: () => {},
      setUser: () => {}
    })

    export default FeedContext

    export class FeedProvider extends Component {
      state = {
        feed: [],
        error: null,
        user: ''
      };

      setFeed = Feed => {
        this.setState({ Feed })
      }

      setError = error => {

        console.error()
        this.setState({ error })
      }

      clearError = () => {
        console.log('context is accessed')
        this.setState({ error: null })
      }

      setUser = user => {
        console.log(user)
        this.setState({ user })
      }

      render() {
        const value = {
          feed: this.state.feed,
          error: this.state.error,
          user: this.state.user,
          setError: this.setError,
          clearError: this.clearError,
          setFeed: this.setFeed,
          setUser: this.setUser
        }

        return (
          <FeedContext.Provider value={value}>
            {this.props.children}
          </FeedContext.Provider>
        )
      }
    }
```

BlogFeed.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import FeedContext from "../../contexts/FeedContext";
    import BlogPost from '../../Components/Container/BlogPost/BlogPost';
    import AccountPanel from '../../Components/AccountPanel/AccountPanel';
    import "./BlogFeed.css";
    import ArticleApiService from "../../services/article-api-service";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    class BlogFeed extends React.Component {

      static contextType = FeedContext;

      state = {
        feed: [],
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.context.clearError()
        ArticleApiService.getPosts()
```

This code takes output from ArticleApiService.getPosts() above,
and uses it to successfully update feed value of the local state

```
      // .then((data) => {
      //   this.setState({ feed: data })
      //   return data
      // })
```

This code is supposed to take the same output from 
ArticleApiService.getPosts() use it to update FeedContext "feed",
it is currently not updating FeedContext

```
          .then(this.context.setFeed)
          .catch(this.context.setError)
      }

      renderPosts() {
        const { feed = [] } = this.context

         return function(){

        }
      }
```

feed would be equal to the value of this.context.feed, if it were
successfully updated ablove, but is not being updated.
The value of feed would be mapped to  so it could 
display the content of each post

```
       renderPosts() {
        const { feed = [] } = this.context
        return feed.map(post =>
          <BlogPost
            key={post.id}
            post={post}
          />
        )
      }

      render() {

        let feed = this.state.feed;

         const { error } = this.context

        return (
          <section className="feed-container">
            <div className="feed-grid">
              <div className="spacerLeft"></div>
              <div className="feed-grid-item">
                <h1>Blog Feed</h1>
```

This code is supposed to display an error if the value of 
 "error", has been updated in the context, which it hasn't.
 Alternatively, the feed is used for else, we get blog posts displayed in 
 our feed, because local state is successfully updated above, but if I use this.renderPosts(), nothing is displayed because FeedContext never gets updated.

```
                 {error

                  ?<p>No Posts have been created, but the good news is that 
                       you can create one 
                    <Link
                    onClick={this.handleLogoutClick}
                    to='/create_post'>
                    here
                 </Link></p>
                  // this.state.feed.length
                  // ? feed.map(post => { return <BlogPost postData={post}> 
                    </BlogPost> })
                  : ?this.renderPosts()
                    }


              </div>
              <div className="spacerRight">

                <div className="side-panels flexed">
                  {/* Future Account Panel Component */}
                  <AccountPanel className="side-panel-content"></AccountPanel>
                </div>

                <div className="side-panels flexed">
                  {/* Future Account Panel Component */}
                  <div className="side-panel-content">Categories</div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        );
      }
    }

    export default BlogFeed;
```

Ultimately, I would like to be able to update the Feed context and retrieve updated values from it as well

Answer (score 0):

```
  state = {
    feed: [],
    error: null,
    user: ''
  };

  setFeed = Feed => {
    this.setState({ Feed })
  }
```

this way you'll have `this.state.feed` and `this.state.Feed` - `feed` doesn't equal `Feed` - make prop unified names, they are case sensitive

Next:

```
.then(this.context.setFeed)
```

it doesn't look like function call, no data passed

Comment: Thanks @xadm, but it turns out that I forgot to wrap the <App/> in <Provider/> tags...